# Masterpage in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am using a masterpage and have created a very simple website. I need to hide and unhide access to some links and buttons using c#. the code works fine in the home link but for some reason I cant get it to work on other links of the webpage
Here is part of the code from the working line that works fine from the link HOME

```
 <td class="style5"><a class="Link2" id="ad" runat="server" href="admin.aspx" style="color: #FFFFFF">Admin</a>
            </td>
        <td class="style5"><a class="Link1" href="login.aspx" style="color: #FFFFFF" id="ab" runat="server">Login</a>

         <asp:Button id="cd" runat="server" Text="Logout" onclick="Button1_Click" 
                Width="100%" BackColor="Red" CausesValidation="False" Font-Bold="True" 
                ForeColor="White" />

            </td>
```

the c#

```
namespace Aptech_Project
{
    public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if ((string)Session["us1"] == "admin")
            {
                ab.Disabled = true;
                ab.Visible = false;
                cd.Visible = true;
                ad.Disabled = false;
                ad.Visible = true;
            }
            else

            {

                ab.Disabled = false;
                ab.Visible = true;              
                cd.Visible = false;               
                ad.Disabled = true;
                ad.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["us1"] = null;
            Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

I have the exact same code on a Page called about us but it does not work on the About us page.Here is the code that is not working

```
<td class="style5"><a class="Link2" href="admin.aspx" style="color: #FFFFFF" id="ad" runat="server">Admin</a>
            </td>

       <td class="style5"><a class="Link1" href="login.aspx" style="color: #FFFFFF" id="ab" runat="server">Login</a>
         <asp:Button id="cd" runat="server" Text="Logout" onclick="Button1_Click" 
                Width="100%" BackColor="Red" CausesValidation="False" Font-Bold="True" 
                ForeColor="White" />
            </td>
```

the c#

```
namespace Aptech_Project
{
    public partial class aboutus : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                if ((string)Session["us1"] == "admin")
                {
                    ab.Disabled = true;
                    ab.Visible = false;
                    cd.Visible = true;
                    ad.Disabled = false;
                    ad.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {

                ab.Disabled = false;
                ab.Visible = true;              
                cd.Visible = false;               
                ad.Disabled = true;
                ad.Visible = false;
                }
            }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["us1"] = null;
            Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure how the page load function works with Master Pages. Does the page load of the master page work first and then the content pages or vise versa.

Please help.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If those links are there in master page why not hide/unhide them in Master page's page load event... that way you can avoid this repetition.

Comment: true. this is only a trial run for a web page I am designing that will have specific links on separate pages hence I cannot add it to the masterpage.

Answer (score 0):

If you're moving to"About Us" from "Home", the problem might be for you're setting the `Session` variable to null.

Comment: well the session variable is NULl as I have not loged in. It is NULL when the Home page loads as well and it works fine. The else block executes if the Session variable is not admin (or NULL) For some reason I cant get it to work when with the other links.

Answer (score 0):

try using `Page.Master.FindControl("controlID")` to find controls in the master page

Comment: please explain how I would use it

Comment: `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button button1 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)Page.Master.FindControl("button_ID_in_master_page");`
`button1.Visible = true`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **FindControl** i recommended to use MASTERTYPE directive to utilize Master page's properties and their controls properties directly.
By following declaration of code in content page you can access properties.

**<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.master" %>**

Then in content page you just have to use MASTER keyword to utilize any properties.

**Like**
Master.lblControl1.Text="Hi";